# jQuery search in an object using a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

## UPDATE

**23 November 2016:**

I was very close to the solution. Rory McCrossan has solved it for me, so I accepted his answer. **BUT** I changed the code for faster developing. I want to share this so you can use it to.

**JSON** *langfile-v1.0.json*

```
{
    "nl": {
        "text1":"Hallo Wereld!",
        "text2":"voorbeeld.com",
        "text3":"Ik hou van Stack Overflow"
    },
    "en":{
        "text1":"Hello World!",
        "text2":"example.com",
        "text3":"I love Stack Overflow"
    }
}
```

**Javascript / jQuery** *script.js*

```
//Creating an GLOBAL object
var languageObject;

//Get the language json file
$.get("langfile-v1.0.json", function(response){
    languageObject = response; //Assign the response to the GLOBAL object
    setLanguage(); //Calling the setLanguage() function
});

//Call this function to set the language
function setLanguage() {
    $("lang").html(function() {
        var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
        var langSupported = false; //Check if the user language is supported
        $.each(languageObject, function(key) {
            if (userLang == key) {
                langSupported = true;
            }
        });
        if (langSupported) {
            //Users language is supported, use that language
            return languageObject[userLang][$(this).html()];
        } else {
            //User language is NOT supported, use default language
            return languageObject.en[$(this).html()];
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML** *page.html*

```
<lang>text1</lang> <br>
<lang>text2</lang> <br>
<lang>text3</lang>
```

## Demo

You can check how this works on JSFiddle (with a slightly different code because I dont know how to inculde the *langfile-v1.0.json* file)

[Click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/promike360/2evjyfah/)

---

## OLD QUESTION POST:

I want to search in a object using a string.

## Example:

**JSON**

```
{
    "nl": {
        "lang":"Nederlands",
        "header-WelcomeText":"Welkom op de website",
        "header-Sub1":"Hoofdpaneel"
    },
    "en": {
        "lang":"English",
        "header-WelcomeText":"Welcome on the website",
        "header-Sub1":"Dashboard"
    }
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var output;
$.get("file.json", function(response){
    output = response; //This is now a object in javascript
});
```

This all works, here what i want:

```
//The jQuery code
$('span .lang').text(output.nl.$(this).attr("data-lang"));

//The HTML code
<span class="lang" data-lang="header-Sub1"></span>
```

I know this will not work, but I know there will be a way to achief this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work there's a few changes you need to make.

- when accessing the key of an object through a variable you need to use bracket notation.
- to reference the element through the `this` keyword you need to run your code within it's scope. To do that you can pass a function to the `text()` method which returns the value you need from the object.
- the `.lang` class is directly on the `span`, so you shouldn't have the space in your selector.

With all that in mind, this should work for you:

```js
var output = {
  "nl": {
    "lang": "Nederlands",
    "header-WelcomeText": "Welkom op de website",
    "header-Sub1": "Hoofdpaneel"
  },
  "en": {
    "lang": "English",
    "header-WelcomeText": "Welcome on the website",
    "header-Sub1": "Dashboard"
  }
}

$('span.lang').text(function() {
  return output.nl[$(this).data("lang")];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="lang" data-lang="header-Sub1"></span>
```

Comment: Wow! My example was just something random to simply explain what I wanted to have. Didn't know I was this close haha. Thanks!

Comment: Haha your answer was so fast that I needed to wait 8 minutes to accept this answer ;P But I have done it